# Uploadify plugin doesn't call Java Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, uploadify

i just started using Uploadify flash plugin instead of standard HTML UI.
And met the next problem:
**when I click "Upload Files" link,that progress is shown and "completed" status is appeared, but in reality - it didn't happened anything,Java Servlet isn't called from backend.**
There is upload servlet and uploading performed next way ***earlier***:

```
< form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="uploadFrame"
action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=${remoteFolder}">...
```

After providing Uploadify plugin, UI ***now*** looks like:

plugin part(configuration):

```
    <script>
...  
         oScript.text+= "$j('#uploadify').uploadify({";
      oScript.text+= "'uploader' : 'kne-portlets/js/lib/uploadify/scripts/uploadify.swf',";
      oScript.text+= "'script'   : '<%= request.getContextPath() %>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=<%= decodedString %>',";
      oScript.text+= "'cancelImg': 'kne-portlets/js/lib/uploadify/cancel.png',";
      oScript.text+= "'folder'   : '<%= decodedString %>',";
      oScript.text+= "'queueID'  : 'fileQueue',";
      oScript.text+= "'auto'     : false,";
      oScript.text+= "'multi'    : false,";
      //oScript.text+= "'sizeLimit' : 1000";
      oScript.text+= "});";
      oScript.text+= "});"; 
...   
</script>
```

'scripts' parameter here points to Java Servlet on backend

`<%= decodedString %>` is folder path, which value is *\\file-srv\demo*

part for uploading:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadify" id="uploadify" />
<a href="javascript:$j('#uploadify').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a>
```

Where is my fault?

'Script' param in plugin config points to Java Servlet on backend and it's done,but Servlet isn't triggered.

error, when 'script' param isn't correct:http://img190.imageshack.us/i/errormm.png/

Thank you for assistance.

Comment: right click > view sources and see how is the `action` realized in html, then copy it to the browser URL and see if it opens

Comment: i have no action param., because use Uploadify plugin, which requires 'script' param. instead. Earlier i used simple form with 'action' and Servlet triggered OK. And now Servlet isn't triggered,because of some problems of 'script' param., as assumed.Do i understand you correctly?

Comment: Sounds more like JS issue. Run Firebug or WebDeveloperToolbar on Firefox and debug the JS code. Post errors/warnings here if you stucks.

Comment: The most strange, that "Net" tab of FireBug is empty after link for uploading is clicked, it means that there is no POST for Servlet. There are no JS errors.

Comment: Thus, the JS was simply not been executed? Debug more. Did it get loaded? Didn't the script src's return 404?

Comment: JS is loaded,because other config of plugin is working - 'auto', 'multi','uploader' parameters. The main issue is in 'script' parameter-part, where servlet is called.
Either it doesn't work or its declaration isn't correct.

Comment: Check generated HTML source for the actual URL. Debug the incoming requests in server --the poor man's way would be creating a Filter listening on `/*` which does a `System.out.println(((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI());`. Although the problem lies a bit higher I think, as you mentioned that the "Net" tab of firebug didn't show any activity.

Comment: Use Fiddler/Firebug to intercept and view request/response. That may throw some light on what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can have a lot of possible causes (also see the comments I posted).

- External JS is not loaded.
- JS code is syntactically/logically invalid.
- Request URL is invalid.
- Servlet is not mapped at all.
- Servlet is mapped on wrong `url-pattern`.
- Servlet failed to start/init.

It's hard to naildown the root cause based on the as far given information.

As you mentioned that you didn't see any request been fired in the "Net" tab of FireBug, I think that the JS code is simply syntactically/logically invalid. Rightclick page and doubleverify generated/printed JS code.

**Update:** I tried to reproduce your problem.

1. I downloaded [jquery.uploadify-v2.1.0 (MIT)](http://www.uploadify.com/_files/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.0.zip), extracted it and put the entire contents in the `/WebContent/uploadify` folder of my (empty) playground web project in Eclipse.
2. I created a `/WebContent/upload.jsp` file as follows:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <title>Uploadify test</title>
           <script src="uploadify/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
           <script src="uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
           <script src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function() {
                   $('#uploadify').uploadify({
                       'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                       'script': 'uploadServlet',
                       'folder': '/uploads',
                       'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png'
                   });
                   $('#upload').click(function() {
                       $('#uploadify').uploadifyUpload();
                       return false;
                   });
               });
           </script>
       </head>
       <body>
           <input id="uploadify" type="file">
           <a id="upload" href="#">Upload</a>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. I created a `com.example.UploadServlet` as follows with little help of [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) (just placed [`commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar`](http://mirrors.kahuki.com/apache/commons/fileupload/binaries/commons-fileupload-1.2.1-bin.zip) and [`commons-io-1.4.jar`](http://www.alliedquotes.com/mirrors/apache/commons/io/binaries/commons-io-1.4-bin.zip) in `/WEB-INF/lib`):

   ```java
   package com.example;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.List;

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

   public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException
       {
           System.out.println("UploadServlet invoked. Here are all uploaded files: ");
           try {
               List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
               for (FileItem item : items) {
                   if (!item.isFormField()) {
                       System.out.println("Name: " + item.getName());
                       System.out.println("Size: " + item.getSize());
                       System.out.println("Type: " + item.getContentType());
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new ServletException(e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. I registered `com.example.UploadServlet` in `web.xml` as follows:

   ```xml
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/uploadServlet</url-pattern>        
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
5. I deployed the project, started the server, went to http://localhost:8080/playground/upload.jsp, selected a random big file from my downloads folder, clicked the `Upload` link, see the upload percentage counter growing to 100% and I finally see the following in the stdout:

   ```
   UploadServlet invoked. Here are all uploaded files: 
   Name: glassfish-v3-windows.exe
   Size: 50402555
   Type: application/octet-stream
   ```

I'm sorry to say, I can't reproduce your problem. At least, the above information should help you to get started "freshly". Hope it helps.

**Update:** as per the comments, the filter expects that it is using the same session. Ok, you can do this fairly easy by changing

```
'<%= request.getContextPath() %>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=<%= decodedString %>',";
```

to

```
'<%= request.getContextPath() %>/uploadFile;jsessionid=${pageContext.session.id}?portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=<%= decodedString %>',";
```

Comment: Seems,that 'script' param is really taken into consideration,because if it refers to non-existing servlet, that HTTP Error message is appeared on UI.Actually, i couldn't find this message in plugin sources.See,please, screen in bottom of the post.

Comment: Okay. *How* did you conclude that the servlet isn't triggered? You literally stated like that in your question. Have you for instance debugged the `doPost()` method? Even the poor man's way with a `System.out.println("Hey, uploadservlet doPost() is invoked!");`? Have you for instance read **all** server logs in the `/logs` folder?

Comment: I just discovered,with help of sniffer,that there is no POST request at all on click for uploading file,i.e. Servlet isn't triggered.
Seems, that problem really in Flash config,so in JS as you said.

Comment: sorry, didn't answer your first question in the comment. I concluded, that Servlet isn't called with help of debug.Earlier, when UI was just form with action=Servlet ,that was ok and Servlet method handleRequest was called OK.method is handleRequset, because Servlet class implements org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler;

Comment: Debug the JS code. More can I really not be of assistance. Use Firebug or Venkman JS Debugger.

Comment: Oooppph!!! BalusC, it was really hard work. I stuck and asked my TL to help me. Because, i implemented UI part,that i forgot in my debug activity? about  filter in another class. And that filter(java method) got null session ID. So this is JsessionID issue,i should share session's value.
here is explanation:
http://request.getattribute.com/2009/09/14/17/

I will be working on it...

Comment: You're absolutely correct about jsessionid.So the root cause is that Flash doesn't set cookies.And now i got another problem - Uploadify cant' pass more than one param in 'script', but i think that's another question. This issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue with uploadify 2.1.4.  I played around with this long enough to figure out that it appears to be a problem with a nested URI path, `i.e. /folder1/folder2/folder3, etc.`  As soon as I changed my path to use the base path (just /folder1, or /uploadServlet like @BalusC was using) the SWF file began sending data to my servlet.