# Using Uploadify to link to a Servlet - Syntax

Tags: java, servlets, uploadify

I have coded up a servlet that I'll be using to process file uploads with Uploadify. Uploadify provides a "Script" section in its implementation, where by default it points to a pre-packaged Upload.php to process file uploads. Obviously, I will not be able to use this since I'm in Java world.

I'd like to know what the syntax would look like where I link Uploadify to my servlet. See below for Uploadify's link to its PHP file in bold. What would this line look like pointed to a servlet instead of PHP file?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    **'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',**
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'auto'      : true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just let the URL point to a servlet which in turn parses the request as you would usually do in case of an `<input type="file">` field. A defacto standard of parsing uploaded files is the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). You can find examples in their *User Guide* section.

You can find a more concrete example of a Servlet which acts on Uploadify requests in the "Update" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272160/uploadify-plugin-doesnt-call-java-servlet/2273711#2273711).

Comment: A servlet **is** a Java class. It look like that you're new to servlets as well. I'd suggest to get yourself through our [servlets info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) to get started with servlets.