# Upload files in JSP/Servlet

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets, upload

i know how upload files in jsp/servlet, i already use fileupload from apache, but i don't know how to return some status of the upload to the user, for example, actually when someone select the file to upload, they have to click in 'upload' button and just when the upload finish the jsp page redirect to the another page.
I want they can see a percentage of how much will take to complete the upload operation.

i already implement a listener using fileupload, but i don't know how to show this information to the user, 'cause just when the upload is finished that i can redirect to another jsp page.

Any ideas ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: If it's still relevant to you, maybe check out: https://www.baeldung.com/upload-file-servlet - full example with response!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in combination with plain HTML `<form>` with `<input type="file">`. To the point, you've got to send multiple simultaneous requests. A form submit with file upload will namely block as long as the upload is in progress.

Your best bet is using JavaScript/Ajax and/or Flash. There are several free file upload components supporting a progress bar, like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) and [SwfUpload](http://swfupload.org/).

If your servlet is well written, you should be able to use it unchanged.

Comment: i already try to use uploadify but nothing happenning well i follow the step in the documentation.
i guess i will try swfupload then.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272160/uploadify-plugin-doesnt-call-java-servlet/2273711#2273711

Comment: i can use swfupload, but i don't know where the file is stored in the end of the upload.

Comment: i already try this approach that you recommend but it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens? What happens not?