# how to work with Uplodify and Servlet/JSP

Tags: jakarta-ee

I too started working with the Uplodify plugin, but i need to call a servlet.
i gave the context path of servlet at script but my servlet is not called.

can any one provide me with a good example for the uplodify-servlet connectivity

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the search? - Maybe this helps: [Uploadify plugin doesn't call Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272160/uploadify-plugin-doesnt-call-java-servlet)